# MySQL Error Code: 1017 permission denied

Tags: mysql, database

I have downloaded the German version of the Northwind sample database. I moved the folder to `/var/lib/mysql` and set the rights to `drwxr-x---`.

Here is an output of `/var/lib/mysql`

```
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql     4096 24. Jan 2016  nordwind
```

However I am able to use the DB but as soon as I try to access to any table I get the following error:

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM artikel;

Error Code: 1017. Can't find file: './nordwind/artikel.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied) 0.0021 sec
```

Here is an output from /var/lib/nordwind

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql   9002 14. Aug 2007  artikel.frm
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql   5204 14. Aug 2007  artikel.MYD
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql   1024 14. Aug 2007  artikel.MYI
```

EDIT: I run the mysql-server on Fedora Server 23

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have SELinux enabled, and you moved the files instead of copying them. Therefore they have their original context (probably `user_home_t` or something similar) rather than the necessary context for MySQL to use them.

To solve the problem, put the files in the correct place in the directory structure (probably `/var/lib/mysql/nordwind` and run `restorecon` on the files.

```
restorecon -r -v /var/lib/mysql/nordwind
```